itsgonnafail error on website after latest Chrome update
I'm getting a websocket error on our website after the latest Chrome update. It seems to be trying to redirect traffic to a url like this ourwebsite.com/blah/blah/itsgonnafail.
I tested on another machine that had not been updated and the error was not appearing. I've also tested on both a Mac and a PC and in both cases, everything works before the update and fails after. The initiator when I trace has a hyperlink of 160d785...js:1
wss://ourwebsiteurl/Location/SubLocation/itsgonnafail

As a side note, the site is working properly on Safari, Firefox, and Safari on an iPhone. We are working on an Android test.
Is anyone else seeing errors after the latest update and if so, does anyone have a fix for this?
I tried disabling WS on the Network tab of Chrome (would not bypass) and testing on both a Mac and a Windows 11 on Parallels that had not been updated yet. Both worked prior to the update. I ran the update to test and both failed after the test indicating this is definitely something going on with the latest Chrome update.
UPDATE: We found the issue. There was a CORS policy update in the latest release that caused a problem with our third party cookie banner. They gave us an updated script to put on our layout pages and the issue is now resolved.

Could you please clarify your update to include the third-party cookie provider you are using and if you have any links to this CORS policy update in Chrome for others to be able to debug and solve this issue?
